# strtotime UK date weirdness

Tags: php

Maybe I need more sleep but I have some weirdness with strtotime I cannot explain.

The UK localised notation for a date is `d/m/Y` which is what I am getting within a CSV from an external source to insert into MySQL (format: `Y-m-d`).

The immediate problem I saw, of course, was that PHP (when using `strtotime`) converted these wrong. Below is an example of a `var_dump` of the field value with the post-`strtotime` `var_dump` after:

```
string(10) "13/07/1992" string(19) "1969-12-31 16:00:00" // This one is odd
string(10) "07/09/1992" string(19) "1992-07-09 00:00:00"
string(10) "09/11/1992" string(19) "1992-09-11 00:00:00"
```

Originally I thought it was because PHP did not support the UK notation ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php ) and believes it is an American date however that does not explain why if I change my function to replace `/` with `-`:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $string_time)))
```

The same dates do work:

```
string(10) "13/07/1992" string(19) "1992-07-13 00:00:00"
string(10) "07/09/1992" string(19) "1992-09-07 00:00:00"
string(10) "09/11/1992" string(19) "1992-11-09 00:00:00"
```

I infact have a test set of 200 dates that all work under the `-` notation.

Shouldn't the same rules apply here according to the documentation?

Comment: Never mind I need more sleep if it is a slash it is american if it is a dash or dot is a european date, sorry for wasting time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The US format uses slashes because that is the convention over there. Normally, dashes aren't used. `strototime()`'s behavior is quite simply:

- Two digits, slash, two digits, slash, four digits? US format (month, then day).
- Two digits, dash, two digits, dash, four digits? International format (day, then month).

A more technical list of formats (and how `strototime()` interprets them) can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

You might also be interested in [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: Indeed, I read that at the last minute and the same applies to dots as well.