# Passing a UK date in a URL

Tags: php, date

I am passing a date in a URL in a UK format as per the following:

http://www.website.com/index.php?from_date=01/04/2013&to_date=12/04/2013

The date range is 1st April 2013 to 12th April 2013.

Then I am using the following PHP to convert it to the YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
<?php

$rpt_from_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET["from_date"]) );
$rpt_to_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET["to_date"]) );

echo $rpt_from_date;
echo "</br>";
echo $rpt_to_date;

?>
```

For some reason this is not working. The above returns the following:

2013-01-04

2013-12-04

It's switching the month and day around.  I want it to return:

2013-04-01

2013-04-12

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `strtotime()` considers `/` separated dates to be US format. Your original URL will need to use eg `to_date=12-04-2013`

Comment: This has nothing to do with URLs, just with how `strtotime` parses dates. And this has been answered many times over...

Comment: `explode` by `/` and parse it yourself, if the format you're giving isn't recognized by `strtotime` there's nothing more you can do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [strtotime UK date weirdness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287904/strtotime-uk-date-weirdness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is reading your time string in the US format (MM/DD/YYYY) because you are using slashes. You could use dashes to give the time: `index.php?from_date=01-04-2013&to_date=12-04-2013`, or convert it yourself:

```
$uktime = implode("-", explode("/", $_GET['from_date']));
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) object, to get php understand in which format you passing date to it.

```
$rpt_from_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET["from_date"]);
echo $rpt_from_date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

I will provide the solution but it is not using the date function:

```
$arr = explode("/",$_GET["from_date"]);
$from_date = $arr[2]."-".$arr[1]."-"$arr[0];
```

Second solution is as following:

```
$from_date = implode(array_reverse(explode("/",$_GET["from_date"])));
```